# Magento Test Automation Framework (Custom Application Area)

Tags: magento-1.7, phpunit, mtaf

I've already setup Magento Test Automation Framework. I've already run the Test Files that comes with it. I would like to know how to create a custom application area. I have this admin extension that doesn't have the admin front name (www.mymage.com/admin) but instead it has this url (www.mymage.com/myextension). As I run the custom test, I'm getting an error of Area "mymanager" is not found in admin. As I traced back the code, I'm noticing in the config.yml file having the "frontend" and "admin" areas being declared so I've tried creating a node under it with this value

```
myextension:
                url: 'http://vm.maps.com/index.php/mymanager'
                base_page_uimap: 'log_in_to_admin'
                uimap_path: 'myextension'
```

I don't know if this is correct but I'm still getting errors.

Comment: As a complete aside, custom admin frontnames are something I personally dislike greatly, especially if the module will be distributed. They 'help' expose what the supposedly secret custom admin frontname is.